# Проблема с обновлением TIBDataSet

Tags: база-данных, delphi, firebird

Все наверное знают, что для обновления данных в IBDataSet нужно просто его переоткрыть, т.е. сделать "Close" и "Open".

1. Но если приложение/клиент, раскидать по двум машинам.
   *Dataset1* (первая машина) редактирует запись - одно поле (при помощи DBNavigator). В событии *DataSetAfterPost*, стоит *IBTransaction.CommitRetaining*. После этого запись в самой БД **обновяется**.

*Dataset2* (вторая машина) уже открыт и в событии "*BeforeRefresh*" делаю *Close*, и *Open* , т.е.

```
    ADataSet.Close;

    ADataSet.SelectSQL.Clear;
    ADataSet.SelectSQL.Add(ARequire);
    ADataSet.Open;

    ADataSet.FetchAll;
```

Запись в *Dataset2* НЕ обновляется
**Что я забыл**?

2. *Delphi10.2*, передача запроса, в стринговую переменную *ARequire*, в дебаге вижу (в конце строки) "'*select * from CONTRACT where ARCHIVE = 1*'#**$**D#$A" - и эта хрень передается в DataSet.

   - хотя, эти 5 строк, я все время использую и проблем с запросами ни когда не было
   - ну как обычно тут пишут, после IBDataBase.Connected false и true - все замечательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, транзакция у Dataset2 (на второй машине) с параметром concurrency, то есть не видит новых записей (или новых версий записей), созданных транзакциями, подтверждёнными после её старта. Используй read_committed (желательно вместе с параметром rec_version).

Про транзакции читай:

http://www.ibase.ru/mga/

http://www.ibase.ru/ibx/#tran_use

http://www.ibase.ru/ibtrans/

Comment: да, чтоб не было ''#**$**D#$A'  в конце строки, приходится вызывать у строковой переменной "Trim". Например: ARequire,**Trim**. -не знаю на сколько это правильно... но это помогает